# Crontab wont run a script

Tags: scripts, cron

I've set a script to run every 10 minutes using cron, but it does not run. It works when I run it manually. `bin` path is `/usr/bin/`.

The script contains:

```
#!/bin/bash
scrot 'screenshot.png' -e 'mv $f /mnt/ftp/screenshots/'
```

Comment: How do you setup the cron ?

Comment: */10 * * * * /root/ss.sh

Answer (score 3):

Try to change your script as follow:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

export DISPLAY=:0    

scrot 'screenshot.png' -e 'mv $f /mnt/ftp/screenshots/'
```

And this because the problem occur because cron uses only a very restricted set of environment variables, through which `DISPLAY` doesn't exists.

Comment: works! thx alot!